# Swift function that swaps two values

Tags: swift

I need to write a function that swaps the contents of any two variables. This is what I have currently but I am getting the error "Cannot assign to value: 'a' is a 'let' constant".

```
func swap<T>(a: T, b: T) {
    (a, b) = (b, a);
}
```

Can somebody please explain why this doesn't work and suggest how to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You need to make the parameters `inout` to be able to do that, like this:

```
func swap<T>(_ a: inout T,_ b: inout T) {
    (a, b) = (b, a)
}
var a = 0, b = 1
swap(&a, &b)
```

Comment: Nice solution. Note that swap(&a, &b) is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters inside your function is immutable so it cannot be swapped , like if you trying to swap two let value:

```
let x = 5
let y = 6
//if you try to swap these values Xcode will tell you to change their declaration to var
```

Here almost the same and to be able to change the values you have to pass inout declaration like below :

```
func swapTwoValues<T>(_ a: inout T, _ b: inout T) {
     (a, b) = (b, a)
}
// call it like this 
var x = 1
var y = 2
swapTwoValues(&x, &y)
// Note that you cannot call it like this: swapTwoValues(&1, &2)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the arguments of functions are constants and are treated as local properties, unless you mark them `inout` and then they are treated as sort of "pass-through" properties that aren't confined to the scope of the function.

```
var kiwi = "kiwi"
var mango = "mango"

func swap<T>(a: inout T, b: inout T) {
    (a, b) = (b, a)
}

swap(&kiwi, &mango)
```

Answer (score 0):

If having to put `&` everywhere or the verbosity of the function annoy you, you could always use a descriptive operator like this:

```swift
infix operator <->: AssignmentPrecedence

func <-> <A>(lhs: inout A, rhs: inout A) {
  (lhs, rhs) = (rhs, lhs)
}

var kenobi = "Hello there!"
var helloThere = "Kenobi..."

helloThere <-> kenobi

print(helloThere, kenobi, separator: "\n")
// Hello there!
// Kenobi...
```

Which I feel looks much nicer. You don't need to use `&` in operators with `inout` parameters – that's how the `+=` and `-=` operators work:

```swift
public extension AdditiveArithmetic {
  static func +=(lhs: inout Self, rhs: Self) {
    lhs = lhs + rhs
  }

  static func -=(lhs: inout Self, rhs: Self) {
    lhs = lhs - rhs
  }
}
```